# I can't discard changes on visual studio git

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-commit, unstage

I was playing with git and github, so was learning how to contribute to opensource projects, so i forked and cloned a repository. Afterwards, i deleted the entire file, only to discover that my commits were still staged. I have tried deleting them to no avail. It bugs me because it keeps showing i have over 10k staged commits and i can't unstage or delete them. I even uninstalled vs code but it's still there. the following screenshot shows the error message i get when i try unstaging and discarding them.
[error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFDVt.png)

here is the other screenshot of before i clicked on it, showing me i have over 10k changes unstaged.[10k files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzzrn.png)

Comment: There’s only three staged, others are unstaged changes. Have you tried `git reset --hard` from command line? Note it will remove all changes you have made so far. VS Code does nothing to git, uninstalling it won’t change what the repository’s state is.

Comment: Thank you, i have done it but the files are still there :(

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal in VSCode and from any directory inside the project type:

```
git reset
```

This should unstage all and allow you to stage files individually

Comment: I already deleted the project, so i cant go into any directory there